# Non linear scaling to show a sol system

Tags: c#, simulations, scale, orbit

In a sol system 2d simulation I have some problems in showing the entire system (ie: eaven planets far away than saturn ) 
letting distinguibles the nearest planet orbits.

[image]

Actualy a use a simple scaling logic like this

```
    double _x = W / 2.0 + ((x ) / maxW) * W;
    double _y = H / 2.0 + ((y ) / maxH) * H;
```

where
`x` is real planet x position (assuming sun at origin (0,0))
`y` is real planet y position 
`W` is canvas width (i.e 512)
`H` is canvas height (i.e 512)

`maxW` and `maxH` are the system real border (or the portion I decide to simulate) : in the example I put 
`maxW = maxH = 20.0 * 149597870700.0;` (20 times the sun earth distance)

What I ask : there's a methot to calculate a (non linear) scaling that let show a bigger portion of the system but keeping some distance
between objects near the center ?

EDIT: Here what I get if I enlarge the system borders: 
`maxW = maxH = 60.0 * 149597870700.0;` (60 times the sun earth distance(UA) )

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [logarithmic scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale) where `drawnRadius = log(actualRadius)`.

You then end up with a spacing like this which shows all the planets quite neatly separated:

[image: solar system logarithmic represenation]
(this representation appears to be using logarithm to base 4)

When you want to apply this to your planetary simulation, you first need to convert the carthesian coordinates (x, y) of each planet to polar coordinates (angle, distance) relative to the center, calculate the logarithm of the distance, convert back to carthesian and draw it.

Comment: I think you put me in the right direction (I missed the polar coordinates  stuff..) , I'll give it a try